# Akavache Invalidate

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, mobile, akavache

I want to delete the object from akavache like this

```
BlobCache.LocalMachine.Invalidate("key");
```

But the compiler got me the error warning 
"The type 'Unit' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'" and it makes me can not compile it

I got no idea how to fix this. I am already trying akavache 5.0.0 and also akavache 4.1.2. I am trying search System.Reactive.Core and the minimum version in nuget is 3.0.0

Answer (score 3):

The older reactive packages aren't available through the standard GUI nuget. So you have to install the older Reactive libraries from the nuget command line

Install-Package System.Reactive.Core -Version 2.2.5.0

But if you have other libraries that depend on Reactive version 3 that won't work and you're kind of out of luck.

I have a pull request for Akavache that makes Akavache compatible with Reactive version 3 that will hopefully be awesome and merged at some point!
https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/pull/367

**UPDATE 11/3/2017**

The latest Alpha version of Akavache is on nuget and supports netstandard/rx3

Comment: i am getting error message when i try to install. it tells me that "Failed to add reference. The package 'akavache.core' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.IdentityModel' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
  Reference unavailable."

Comment: as I understand this System.IdentityModel exist in .net 4.0 only and i dont know why it is added as a dependency. 5.0 doesnt have it.